# how to parse through the expression if it has no space?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm working on a project to convert postfix to prefix. The code works fine if I add spaces between the operands and operators, but it will not if the characters are have no space between. The sample i used is "AB + CD+*"

here is my code.

```
class PostfixToPrefix {
    
    public static String Postfix_To_Prefix (String Postfix) throws SyntaxError {
        
        // declare the operand stack 
        Stack<String> operand = new Stack<>(); 
        
        // declare the tokenize function 
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer (Postfix);
        
        // while loop to get the next token while there are more tokens 
        while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = tokens.nextToken();
            
            // if the token is an operand push into the stack 
            if(If_Operand(token)) {
                operand.push(token);
            } 
            else { // if the token is an operator pop two operands 
                String operand2 = operand.pop();
                String operand1 = operand.pop(); 
                String experssion = token + " " + operand1 + " " + operand2; // create a string with an operator followed by the two operands
                operand.push(experssion); 
            }
        }
        
        // syntax error is thrown if empty stack is popped
            if(operand.isEmpty()) {
                throw new SyntaxError("Stack is empty"); 
            }
                String Experssion = operand.pop(); // pop the prefix expression into a string 
                 
             // syntax error is thrown if the stack is not empty after the conversion is complete
           if(!operand.isEmpty()) {
               throw new SyntaxError(" Stack is not Empty "); 
           }
                
           
           return Experssion; //return the prefix expression 
    }
    
    // helper method to decide if the token is  an operand
    private static boolean If_Operand(String token) {
        return !token.equals("+") && !token.equals("-") && !token.equals("/") && !token.equals("*"); 
    }

}
```

I tried the split method and it did not work.
I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Since your operands are all single characters, I suggest using method [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int,int)) (in class `java.lang.String`). I also suggest that you [edit] your question and post some sample postfix expressions along with your expected resulting prefix expressions for those postfix expressions.

Comment: Format _Postfix_ before the _StringTokenizer_,  `Postfix = Postfix.replace("+", " + ").replaceAll(" +", " ");`.

Comment: Should the result of converting `AB + CD+*` to prefix be: `*+AB+CD`?

Comment: Yes, that's how the result should be

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it assumes that every token in the postfix expression is separated by a space. So when you have a postfix expression like `"AB + CD+*"`, the StringTokenizer will tokenize it as `["AB", "+", "CD+*"]` instead of `["A", "B", "+", "C", "D", "+", "*"]`.

To correctly tokenize this expression, you'll need a different approach. You can scan through each character in the postfix expression string and decide whether it's an operand or an operator.

Here's a modified version of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

class PostfixToPrefix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a postfix expression (e.g. AB + CD + *):");
        String postfix = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            String prefix = PostfixToPrefix.Postfix_To_Prefix(postfix);
            System.out.println("The prefix expression is:");
            System.out.println(prefix);
        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String Postfix_To_Prefix(String Postfix) throws SyntaxError {

        // Declare the operand stack
        Stack<String> operand = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Postfix.length(); i++) {
            char ch = Postfix.charAt(i);

            // Skip spaces
            if (ch == ' ') {
                continue;
            }

            // If the character is an operand, push it into the stack
            if (If_Operand(ch)) {
                operand.push(String.valueOf(ch));
            } else { 
                // If the character is an operator, pop two operands
                String operand2 = operand.pop();
                String operand1 = operand.pop();
                String expression = ch + " " + operand1 + " " + operand2; 
                operand.push(expression);
            }
        }

        // Throw syntax error if empty stack is popped
        if (operand.isEmpty()) {
            throw new SyntaxError("Stack is empty");
        }
        String Expression = operand.pop(); 

        // Throw syntax error if the stack is not empty after the conversion is complete
        if (!operand.isEmpty()) {
            throw new SyntaxError("Stack is not empty");
        }

        return Expression; 
    }

    // Helper method to decide if the character is an operand
    private static boolean If_Operand(char ch) {
        return ch != '+' && ch != '-' && ch != '/' && ch != '*';
    }

}

class SyntaxError extends Exception {
    public SyntaxError(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
    

}
```

The output for the `AB + CD+*` would be:

[image]

Note that:

1. The method `If_Operand` now takes a `char` as an argument instead of a `String`.
2. Instead of tokenizing the input string, we loop through each character and process it.